# Apache Beam pipeline running on Dataflow failed to read from KafkaIO: SSL handshake failed

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow

I'm building an Apache Beam pipeline to read from Kafka as an unbounded source.

I was able to run it locally using direct runner.

However, the pipeline would fail with the attached exception stack trace, when run using Google Cloud Dataflow runner on the cloud.

It seems it's ultimately the [Conscrypt Java library](https://github.com/google/conscrypt) that's throwing [`javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unable to parse TLS packet header`](https://github.com/google/conscrypt/blob/1.1.x/common/src/main/java/org/conscrypt/ConscryptEngine.java#L782). I'm not really sure how to address this issue.

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to start reading from source: org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kafka.KafkaUnboundedSource@33b5ff70
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.WorkerCustomSources$UnboundedReaderIterator.start(WorkerCustomSources.java:783)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation$SynchronizedReaderIterator.start(ReadOperation.java:360)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.runReadLoop(ReadOperation.java:193)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.start(ReadOperation.java:158)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:75)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.process(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1227)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.access$1000(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:135)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker$6.run(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:966)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SslAuthenticationException: SSL handshake failed
        org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kafka.KafkaUnboundedReader.start(KafkaUnboundedReader.java:126)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.WorkerCustomSources$UnboundedReaderIterator.start(WorkerCustomSources.java:778)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation$SynchronizedReaderIterator.start(ReadOperation.java:360)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.runReadLoop(ReadOperation.java:193)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.start(ReadOperation.java:158)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:75)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.process(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1227)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.access$1000(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:135)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker$6.run(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:966)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SslAuthenticationException: SSL handshake failed
        java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:206)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kafka.KafkaUnboundedReader.start(KafkaUnboundedReader.java:112)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.WorkerCustomSources$UnboundedReaderIterator.start(WorkerCustomSources.java:778)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation$SynchronizedReaderIterator.start(ReadOperation.java:360)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.runReadLoop(ReadOperation.java:193)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.start(ReadOperation.java:158)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:75)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.process(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1227)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.access$1000(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:135)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker$6.run(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:966)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SslAuthenticationException: SSL handshake failed
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unable to parse TLS packet header
        org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap(ConscryptEngine.java:782)
        org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap(ConscryptEngine.java:723)
        org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap(ConscryptEngine.java:688)
        org.conscrypt.Java8EngineWrapper.unwrap(Java8EngineWrapper.java:236)
        org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.handshakeUnwrap(SslTransportLayer.java:464)
        org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.doHandshake(SslTransportLayer.java:328)
        org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.handshake(SslTransportLayer.java:255)
        org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.prepare(KafkaChannel.java:79)
        org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:460)
        org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:398)
        org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:460)
        org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:238)
        org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:214)
        org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:190)
        org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureCoordinatorReady(AbstractCoordinator.java:219)
        org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureCoordinatorReady(AbstractCoordinator.java:205)
        org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.fetchCommittedOffsets(ConsumerCoordinator.java:468)
        org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.refreshCommittedOffsetsIfNeeded(ConsumerCoordinator.java:450)
        org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.updateFetchPositions(KafkaConsumer.java:1772)
        org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.position(KafkaConsumer.java:1411)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kafka.KafkaUnboundedReader.setupInitialOffset(KafkaUnboundedReader.java:641)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kafka.KafkaUnboundedReader.lambda$start$0(KafkaUnboundedReader.java:106)
        java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: This looks more like a networking issue. Have you set any non-default [network parameters](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/specifying-networks)?

Comment: @LefterisS Thanks! It seems I've setup the pipeline to be in the same network/subnetwork as my Kafka servers though.

Comment: I'm with google cloud platform support and I can tell you that usually these turn out to be transient issues of relatively small duration and impact. Are you still dealing with this problem?

Comment: @LefterisS Just tried it and unfortunately the issue is still there.

Comment: Are you building with Java8 and not a newer version?

Comment: @FridayPush Yes Java 8 used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like Conscrypt causes SSL errors in many cotexts like this. Dataflow worker in Beam 2.9.0 has an option to disable this. Please try. `--experiment=disable_conscrypt_security_provider`. Alternately, you can try Beam 2.4.x, which does not enable Conscrypt.

Comment: Thanks Raghu! I'm able to resolve the issue by upgrading to use [Beam SDK 2.9.0](https://beam.apache.org/blog/2018/12/13/beam-2.9.0.html). Mentioned in the release doc: "Dataflow runner was updated to **not** use Conscrypt as the default security provider."

Comment: For 2.9.0 the final release disables Conscrypt by default. There is a flag to enable it `--experiments=enable_conscrypt_security_provider`

Comment: What is the default security provider in 2.9.0 then?